# NSOutlineView overwrites rows on the transparent header

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstableview

I want to have a transparent header for NSOutlineView. When I made the header transparent, rows overwrite the header when scrolling (when the header is not transparent it's not visible because scrolled rows slide under the header). Is there a way to make the header transparent and rows not overwriting it? Watch the demo: https://youtu.be/0znPhF-_mYo

It's just a regular NSOutlineView with overloaded NSTableHeaderCell:

```
@implementation NFinderHeaderCell
    - (void)drawWithFrame:(NSRect)cellFrame inView:(NSView *)controlView {
        [NSColor.clearColor setFill];
        NSRectFill(cellFrame);
        [self drawInteriorWithFrame:cellFrame inView:controlView];
    }
@end
```

which makes the header transparent. After the header is transparent, rows are displayed over the header when scrolling.

That's all the code. To change NSTableHeaderCell into the overloaded one (NFinderHeaderCell) you must add:

```
for (NSTableColumn *col in myOutline.tableColumns)
    [col setHeaderCell:[[NFinderHeaderCell alloc] init]];
```

No more code involved.
I've tried to change size of NSClipView, NSOutlineView, changing contentView and documentView of NSScrollView, tried to move NSTableHeaderView outside the NSScrollView. Nothing works. NSOutlineView always scrolls rows under the header.
[This picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTVlS.jpg) explains the standard cocoa NSOutlineView problem. Outline view rows are displayed OVER THE ENTIRE scroll view area. The header is just displayed ON TOP of the outline view instead of being displayed ABOVE the outline view. So it's not possible to have transparent header view???

Comment: Post a [mre] please.

Comment: It's just a regular NSOutlineView with overloaded NSTableHeaderCell:  
- (void)drawWithFrame:(NSRect)cellFrame inView:(NSView *)controlView  
{  
  [NSColor.clearColor setFill];  
  NSRectFill(cellFrame);  
  [self drawInteriorWithFrame:cellFrame inView:controlView];  
}  
which makes the header transparent. After the header is transparent, rows are displayed over the header when scrolling.

Comment: Post the code in the question please.

Comment: Code in comments is difficult to read - even if it is just one line. So always edit your question directly. See also [ask].

Comment: This might be a silly question but - why don't you just draw the background to be the color of your intended background instead of transparent?

Comment: Because the background (superview) is semi transparent.